# 'esapi' is undefined in Websphere 7

Tags: eclipse, installation, websphere-7, esapi

Have been following the esapi4java-core-2.0-install-guide.pdf for Eclipse and applying it in a Websphere 7.5 environment.

Step 1 - I added the esapi.jar in the libraries (Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries tab > Add External JARs).

Step 2- I located the esapi & validation .properties files in a folder on my machine.

Step 3 - I selected to add esapi for all run configurations (Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs). I highlighted WebSphere Application Server v7.0 JRE, selected "Edit" and added esapi.jar to that library list. On that same form, I added the -Dorg.owasp.esapi.resources="/path/to/.esapi" argument to the Default VM Arguments prompt, the path to where my esapi & validation .properties files are located.

Here's the code on the JSP page that fails:

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function validateForm()
{

    var userURL = "http://www.google.com";
    var isValidURL = ESAPI.validator().isValidInput("URLContext", userURL, "URL", 255, false); 
    if (isValidURL) {
        alert("true");
    } else {
    alert("false");
    }
}

</script>
```

Upon executing this bit of code, I get the error:
'ESAPI' is undefined (which happens on the var isValidURL statement).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you imported esapi in the jsp.

Try this:

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ page import="java.net.*, org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI, org.owasp.esapi.Validator" %>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function validateForm()
{

    var userURL = "http://www.google.com";
    var isValidURL = <% ESAPI.validator().isValidInput("URLContext", userURL, "URL", 255, false); %>
    if (isValidURL) {
        alert("true");
    } else {
    alert("false");
    }
}

</script>
```

Also note, I'd highly suggest doing the validation in the receiving controller and not in the jsp... the overhead for JSP compilation is murder without adding the overhead of parsing input.  The other warning I'll give you is that if you note esapi documentation, calling `isValidInput()` ignores canonicalization which is absolutely critical.  You'll want to use `getValidInput()` instead.  If you feel you need to use `isValidInput()` then you'll want to ensure you make a manual call to `canonicalize()` which is a method in the `Encoder` class.  Also, please note that this line:

```
var isValidURL = ESAPI.validator().isValidInput("URLContext", userURL, "URL", 255, false);
```

is making a critical mistake in that ESAPI is not a `JavaScript` library.  This call should look like this:

```
var isValidURL = <% ESAPI.validator().isValidInput("URLContext", userURL, "URL", 255, false); %>
```

And in general, as stated above, you want to do this validation on the controller that will be using this jsp as input, not on the jsp itself.  (Scriptlets are slow and should be avoided.)

Comment: I added the import statement - thank you - but am still getting the same error. Because the installation instructions are not clear (about which JRE to assign the VM arguments, of which I arbitrarily to WebSphere Application Server v7.0 JRE), I also tried setting the generic VM argument in the Admin Console > Application Servers > (my server) > Java and Process Management > Process Definition > Java Virtual Machine. This also made no difference. I tried adding systemproperties in the server.xml to point at the two .properties files - still not working. Ideas?

Comment: Are you getting a stack trace or a Browser error?  If its a stack trace, add it to the question.  If its from the browser, modify your assignment to `isValidURL`

Comment: avgvstvs - your corrections did address my reported problem - thanks. Now I have a new prob. ESAPI.properties is found but am getting "Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /WEB-INF/tiles-components/frm/main.jsp in application (myapp)EAR. Exception created : com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.ProgressListener". I did download & add org.apache.commons.fileupload.jar to my EAR's dependencies but that didn't fix it. What's missing?

Comment: The exact lib you want is here:  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload

Comment: I would make sure that the lib actually made it into the server's classpath.  If you're using maven/gradle you'll probably have to run a "clean" before you build.

Comment: I figured out this latest issue. Even though I added this jar to my app's EAR, I still needed to reference this jar in the J2EE Modules settings for my app's Web project (select Web project > Project > Properties > Java EE Module Dependencies > J2EE Modules). Doing this go me past this exception. The page now displays but am getting a new error but appears due to how I implemented the validator code so it looks like I'm good going forward. PS - do NOT enclose the esapi.properties file path with quotes in the VM argument even though the installation instructions show it.